# Restoring Win7 system drive image from primary hard drive (not CD/DVD)?

Tags: hard-drive, restore, disk-image

I managed to mess up my c:\windows. Windows still runs but many apps fail and after thorough investigation it turned out the system installation is beyond repair (tried sfc and everything else).
I do not have the time to reinstall and configure everything from scratch but I happen to have created a system image in .v2i and .gho formats in the past but coincidentally my DVD reader broke recently so I cannot boot from a CD/DVD.
From the last time when I needed to restore a Norton Ghost system drive image I clearly remember that a bootable CD/DVD was mandatory.
Is there any application that can do recover the image from the hard drive? Converting the .gho/.v2i image to another format and restoring with said app is acceptable, is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a:
[Norton Ghost Bootable USB](http://reboot.pro/topic/12832-2010-norton-ghost-15-on-usb-thumb-drive-how-to-make-%E2%80%93-tutorial-guide/)